# Django python ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, django

I have this code to in my views.py that will export to excel, i combined two query in 1 loop but i receive this error `Exception Type: ValueError at /export_reportF/ Exception Value: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

```
    reports = TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords.objects.filter(
        fmCustomerID__company_name__in=company.values_list('fmCustomerID__company_name')).order_by('-inputdate')
    daily = FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier.objects.filter(id__in=reports.values_list('fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID'))
    pairs = [reports, daily]

    for report, day in pairs:
        writer.writerow(
            [
                smart_str(report.id),
                smart_str(report.dateSubmitted),
                smart_str(report.fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID),
                smart_str(day.fmCustomerLocationID),
                smart_str(day.contact_number),
                smart_str(day.fmCustomerSectionID),
                smart_str(day.bodyTemperature),
                smart_str(report.q1Answer),
                smart_str(report.q2Answer),
            ]
        )

    return response
```

this is the traceback `Exception Type: ValueError at /export_reportF/ Exception Value: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Desktop\ContractTracingProject\TracingSettings\TracingApp\views.py" in export_reportF
  1301.     for report, day in pairs:

Exception Type: ValueError at /export_reportF/
Exception Value: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: can you able to provide error log

Comment: @M_x , okay, please wait

Comment: replace line 3 with pairs = zip(reports, daily)

Comment: do you mind to post your answer? so i can mark your as correct answer

Comment: @marvin I've posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 3 reads

```
pairs = [reports, daily]
```

What this gives you is a list which contains two lists. If you loop over it, it will loop twice, first giving you the reports list and then the daily list. Try this:

```
for item in pairs:
    print(item)
    print(type(item))
```

That should make the problem obvious. The solution is to replace line 3 with this:

```
pairs = zip(reports, daily)
```

Which will give you an iterable of pairs, where each pair has one report and one day in it.